# Dual boot - Linux/Windows time mismatch with both using UTC

Tags: linux, windows, time

I'm dual-booting a fully updated Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. Every time I shut down the system from Linux and then boot into Windows, I see the time on Windows is about 3 hours too late; manually synchronizing with Internet time fixes this until the next time I shut down from Linux.

I made sure both OSs are reading the RTC as UTC; on Windows I have `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\RealTimeIsUniversal` set to `1`, and Linux `timedatectl` shows `RTC in local TZ: no`, yet the issue persists. Both OSs seem to write their different time values to the RTC while shutting down, as I can see it on my BIOS menu.

I don't wish to use localtime for both. Is there a way to fix this?

Additional information:
I'm aware of the Win10 bug where `RealTimeIsUniversal` had to be a `QWORD` instead of a `DWORD`; tried using that and it's still not working. I also tried disabling Windows' automatic time sync and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried setting both systems to use local time?

Comment: @FernandoD'Andrea I don't wish to do this. Re-read my question.

Comment: This article may help https://www.howtogeek.com/323390/how-to-fix-windows-and-linux-showing-different-times-when-dual-booting/

Comment: @Biswapriyo I already tried that. Re-read my question.

Comment: @Martin Yes, you don't want it, but we're investigating the issue, right? But, of course, you do as you please.

Comment: @FernandoD'Andrea what insight do you expect to gain from this test?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04

I found that the Windows Time service only started when I requested a time sync through the settings page

Using the Computer Management console, I set Windows Time to start automatically on boot - this fixed the problem :-)